# How to cancel register an app as a Hotspot Helper (NEHotspotHelper)?

Tags: ios, nehotspothelper

I wrote an app that registered as a Hotspot Helper by method below:

```
[NEHotspotHelper registerWithOptions:queue:handler:]
```

which is [documented here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/networkextension/nehotspothelper/1618965-registerwithoptions?language=objc).

After registered , as the document said

> Once this API is invoked successfully, the application becomes eligible to be launched in the background and participate in various hotspot related functions.

Everything walks great.

But, how could I cancel the registration without dispatch a new release ?  I want to provide an local configuration , so user could remove my app from hotspot helper.

1. I tried not to call registerWithOptions:queue:handler after user config, but iOS system still launch the app in the background.
2. And I know that I could disable some code in the handler (the 3rd parameter), but I just want to disable the app from launching in the background.

Does Apple provide some method to do that ? I searched everywhere with no result. Thanks for some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked the same question in apple's forum.

The answer is : There’s currently no way to do this.

The link is https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/227038#227038